# slicebox doesn't show any animation

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am having difficulties with slicebox. I have checked every idea, followed the tutorial, but I'm missing the animation. I think it just doesn't start up, because the first picture in the slide appears, but nothing happens.

CSS included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slicebox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
```

JQuery is the latest version

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.46884.js"></script>
```

The html seems right

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">

<li>
   <a href="#" target="_blank">
   <img src="slider/image1.jpg" alt="image1"/> 
   </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
  <img src="slider/image2.jpg" alt="image1"/> 
  </a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And just before the /body tag at the end

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slicebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#sb-slider').slicebox({
            orientation : 'v',
            autoplay : true,
            });

</script>
```

What is wrong? I don't know much about the jquery but I have tried many variables, probably there is something I can't see. I appreciate any help.